# Hibernate: separate sql query for every collection

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a Person class that has a collection of Contacts. Everything works ok, I get the list of persons with their contacts. However, in log I see that a separate query is made to read collection of every person. That is too bad.
How to make hibernate make a join to read all the data in one query? I use JPA.

This is the person class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl1")
public class PersonItem implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @Column(name="col1")
    private String guid;
    .....
    @ElementCollection(targetClass = ContactItem.class,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name="tbl2",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="col2"))
    private List<ContactItem> contacts;
    ....
}
```

This is the contact class

```
@Embeddable
@Table(name = "tbl2")
public class ContactItem implements Serializable {

    @Column(name="col1")
    private String guid;

    @Column(name="col3")
    private String info;
}
```

This is the way I get the list of persons:

```
Query query = em.createQuery("Select p from PersonItem p WHERE p.guid IN (:guids)");
query.setParameter("guids", guids);
List<PersonItem> list=query.getResultList();
```

And this what I see in log (I have three persons in DB):

```
Hibernate: select personitem0_.col1 as col1_0_, personitem0_.col4 as col2_0_, personitem0_.col2 as col3_0_, personitem0_.col3 as col4_0_ from tbl1 personitem0_ where personitem0_.col1 in (? , ? , ?)
Hibernate: select contacts0_.col2 as col1_1_0_, contacts0_.col1 as col2_1_0_, contacts0_.col3 as col3_1_0_ from tbl2 contacts0_ where contacts0_.col2=?
Hibernate: select contacts0_.col2 as col1_1_0_, contacts0_.col1 as col2_1_0_, contacts0_.col3 as col3_1_0_ from tbl2 contacts0_ where contacts0_.col2=?
Hibernate: select contacts0_.col2 as col1_1_0_, contacts0_.col1 as col2_1_0_, contacts0_.col3 as col3_1_0_ from tbl2 contacts0_ where contacts0_.col2=?
```

Comment: Try LAZY in place of EAGER in that case you may not see the additional queries, the reason is with EAGER loading whenever you fetch a single instance of PersonItem it is bounded to fetch all the associated entities.

Comment: @Bilbo Baggins But I need it to be loaded at once.

Comment: Do you really need to use `@ElementCollection`?

Comment: @JimJim2000 if it is necessary to load it then the answer by Serghey seems to be worth trying.

Comment: @v.ladynev I just learn hibernate, and I don't know how else I can annotate collection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please, begin from a more simple mapping. Use plural names, and column prefixes.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "persons")
public class Person {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "f_guid")
    private String guid;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Contact> contacts;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "contacts")
public class Contact {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "f_guid")
    private String guid;

    @Column(name = "f_info")
    private String info;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)    
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_person")
    private Person person;

}
```

`Person` is associated to `contacts` by a foreign key `fk_person` in the `contacts` table.

**Update**

Looks like `JPQL` overrides a default fetching strategy. You need to specify a fetch explicitly

```
select p from PersonItem p left join fetch p.contacts WHERE p.guid IN (:guids)
```

If you have duplicates, cause of joins, you can use `distinct`

```
select distinct p from PersonItem p left join fetch p.contacts WHERE p.guid IN (:guids)
```

Comment: I did `@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER) @JoinColumn(name = "col2") private List<ContactItem> contacts;` Result is the same - 4 queries. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Thank you for your help. Yes, the problem was in JPQL. So I now have one query. The problem is that in result list I have 7 person while in DB I have only 3 persons (one person with 4 contacts, one with 2 and one without contacts). How to fix it?

Comment: By the way I use `@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER) @JoinColumn(name = "col2") private List<ContactItem> contacts;`

Comment: Yes, it helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try [@Fetch](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/annotations/Fetch.html) on your relation.
Also i would suggest to use `@OneToMany` relation int this case

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "person", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN) //You can use SUBSELECT as well
private List<ContactItem> contacts;
```

You can read more about fetching strategies [here](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-fetching-strategies-examples/)

> 1. fetch-“join” = Disable the lazy loading, always load all the collections and entities.
> 2. fetch-“select” (default) = Lazy load all the collections and entities.
> 3. batch-size=”N” = Fetching up to ‘N’ collections or entities, *Not record*.
> 4. fetch-“subselect” = Group its collection into a sub select statement.

Comment: No, it didn't help. Maybe because I use JPA.

Comment: Why do you need `@Embeddable`? Is it realy needed or it can be replaced with simple `@Entity`? My suggestion is that this is the cause of the problem.

Comment: I just study JPA and try different solutions. I thought this is the right relation according to specs. What can be affects of using @OneToMany instead?

Comment: For me this case looks more like `@OneToMany` relation. This should also make `@Fetch` annotaion work.

Comment: I did `@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER) @JoinColumn(name = "col2") private List<ContactItem> contacts;` but the result is the same - 4 queries. How to fix it?

Comment: Did you try it with `@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)` or `@Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)`?

Comment: I tried and with @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN) - result is the same. It seems to me that this annotation is ignored as I use jpa provider.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111097/discussion-between-serghey-bishyr-and-jimjim2000).

Comment: Serghey, thank you for your help. The problem was in JPQL. See the answer of v.ladynev.